# Is $f(a_1,\dots , a_n) = (f_1(a_1), \dots, f_n(a_n))$ really a function?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, functions, notation

This came up in part of another question and   I think it needs an own thread.

A user said that we can extend any function $f:A\rightarrow B$ to $f:A^n\rightarrow B^n$ and write
\begin{align}
f(a_1,\dots , a_n) = (f_1(a_1), \dots, f_n(a_n)) \tag 1
\end{align}
And for each $f_i$ we have
\begin{align}
f_1, \dots, f_n:A \rightarrow B \tag 2
\end{align}
**But I don't follow why.**

I know the function notation $g: X^n \rightarrow Y^n$, $x\mapsto g(x)$, where $x\in X^n$ and $g(x)\in Y^n$.
So for each $g_i$ we have
\begin{align}
g_1, \dots, g_n :X^n \rightarrow Y \tag 3
\end{align}
And we often write
\begin{align}
 g(x_1, \dots, x_n)=
  (
  g_1(x_1, \dots, x_n),
  \dots, 
   g_n(x_1, \dots, x_n)
   ) \tag 4
\end{align}
**And not**
\begin{align}
 g(x_1, \dots, x_n)
 =(g_1(x_1),\dots,  g_n(x_n))
\tag 5
\end{align}
So I don't understand the notation in $(1)-(2)$ and why it is correct. I know the notation in $(3)-(4)$ well, but can't wrap my head around $(1)-(2)$.

Comment: set $g_i(a_1, \ldots , a_n) := f_i(a_i)= f(a_i)$. does this help?

Comment: $f_i(a_i)= f(a_i)$ is nonsense.

Comment: is it? each $f_i$ is equal to $f$, isn't it?

Comment: No, $f_i $ is a function defined on A and $f$ is a function defined on $A^n$

Comment: Why are all these occurrences of $f$ embroidered with subscripts? Why confuse $f$ and its "extension". Surely we define a *new* function $F:A^n \to B^n$ by $F:(a_1,\dots,a_n)\mapsto (f(a_1),\dots,f(a_n))$ and that's it?

Comment: @ancientmathematician Hi! Maybe I did a typo in $(1)$, do you mean $(f_1(a_1), \dots, f_n(a_n))$ is wrong? Should it be $ (f(a_1), \dots, f(a_n)) $ instead....?

Comment: Definitely: after all there are no $f_i$ in play at that stage. (Your stuff in (4)(5)(6) is all OK btw, but not really relevant).

Comment: Which was "another question"?

Comment: @Fred oh I see why you got confused. I meant the $f:A\to B$, not the "extension"